# SUMPRODUCT coercion in Excel

Tags: excel

Given the following Excel sheet:

```
A1 = 10
A2 = 20
A3 = 30
```

I know / understand why `SUMPRODUCT( 0+(A1:A3>0) )` returns 3 (the 3 boolean values are being coerced in to integers due to the addition).

Why does `SUMPRODUCT( 1+(A1:A3>0) )` return 6? (and increasing the constant gives us a result of Constant*N + N.

Is this a documented feature of Excel, or just some weird oddity that I've stumbled across?

For the sake of clarity, these formulas are not array formulas, and Im using Excel 2003.

Comment: What do you _expect_ it to return, if not `6`?

Comment: As an abuse of order of operations I suppose one could expect `1 + (sum of array values) = 4`, but Barry's answer explains why that's not the case. The addend is applied to each member of the array before they are summed.

Comment: ...and of course the "normal" use of SUMPRODUCT as per the first formula - =SUMPRODUCT( 0+(A1:A3>0) ) wouldn't work as expected if that **weren't** the case - zero needs to be added to every value in the array to co-erce every value in the array.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That formula returns 6 because in your example A1:A3 are all > 0 so A1:A3>0 returns this array

`{TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}` and when you do some sort of calculation on `TRUE/FALSE` values `TRUE` becomes 1 and `FALSE` becomes zero so with

`1+{TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}`

you get

`{2;2;2}`

which `SUMPRODUCT` sums to get 6

You'd get the same result with `SUM` but "array entered" i.e.

`=SUM(1+(A1:A3>0))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

the logic and result is the same in both

The constant 1 is always added to every element in the array - that sort of "array math" is standard in excel

Comment: Ah, got it - I thought the array of {T;T;T} was being evaluated as a group, not treating the constant as an array multiplier.  Many thanks!  Unfortunately I cant upvote your answer yet, but will come back as soon as I have the rep points.